# Influxdb select last specific value from measurement

Tags: influxdb

My jenkins send result of all tests to  one influxdb measurement,
the values of the measurement are test_name status and more,
when the value of status in the measurement is 0 it means that the test fails and if is 1 the test passed,
i want to select the last spesific test_name that jenkins send to influx if his status is 0 show me the test_name and if his status is 1 dont show me.

```
SELECT last(test_name) FROM db  WHERE testname=example AND status = 0
```

this command show me the last example testname that is status is 0 but i need something else.

what i need is for him to check what his latest status is, and if he is 1 do not give me anything back,

Comment: Why do you need this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query to get the last value inserted based on your given condition :

```
select test_name from yourmeasurement order by time desc where testname='example' and status=0 limit 1
```

Here you need to order by data in the `descending` order and then select the top 1 query. Since data insertion is time series, your need not to provide time because its automatically taken.